# Break up a polygon into smaller ones

Tags: python, geometry, gis, geodjango

I am working with geodjango and I want to breakup a 2D Rectangular Polygon into smaller ones.

My input is a big rectangle and I want to subdivide it in smaller rectangles. The sum of the smaller rectangles must be the original rectangle.

All subrectangles should be equal size.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, do you want to break it up in triangles, subdivide into smaller rectangles, random patches... There's many ways that you *could* do this. We can help better if you give a clearer picture of what you want as a result.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the indefinition

My input is a big rectangle and I want to subdivide it in smaller rectangles.

The sum of the smaller rectangles must be the original rectangle.

Comment: Should the small rectangles all be of equal size? (also, if possible you should edit the original question to add this information, instead of letting it sit in comments).

Comment: So if you divided it into four equal quarters, that would solve your question as stated.  Are you saying you don't know how to do that? Or is there more to your problem?

Comment: I'm with brainjam. I don't see what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

1. Pick any point inside the rectangle
2. Draw two lines through it parallel to the edges of the rectangle.  Now you've divided your rectangle into four smaller ones.

Comment: ...of course the horizontal and vertical lines must be relative the the sides of the rectangle. Otherwise, your four sub-shapes might not be rectangular.